# Vue 1.0 -> 2.0 router.start Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Previously using `router.start` w/ Vue 1.0. Migrating to Vue 2.0+, and running into issues (without clear errors) when addressing this deprecation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-router.html#router-start-replaced

Previously, in `main.js` -

```
-router.start(
-  App,
-  "#flightdeck-app",
-  () => { console.log(`app rev ${REVISION}. INTERNAL mode '${INTERNAL}'`) }
-)
```

Where `App` is a root component that initializes stores and renders the rest of the component tree. Replacing it with the below fails—no errors from `npm run dev` nor anything in the console.

I see:

- The App component rendering its `<header>`
- The App component *not* rendering its `<router-view>`.
- No errors in the console.

---

`main.js` mounts the app (we load the App component):

```
// main.js
import Vue from "vue"
import VueRouter from "vue-router"
import App from "./App"
import Overview from "./components/Overview.vue"
import ItemList from "./components/ItemList.vue"

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  linkActiveClass: "active",
  routes: [
    { path: "/", component: Overview },
    // Other paths
    { path: "*", redirect: "/" }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach(function () {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
})

export const app = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({router, App}, App)).$mount("#flightdeck-app")
```

The `App` component looks like the following (and we don't see the `<router-view>` render):

```
// App.vue
<template>
<div id="app">
<header>
  <div class="mark">
    <h1><router-link to="/">flightdeck</router-link></h1>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="content">
  <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
    <keep-alive>
      <router-view :state="state" class="view">
      </router-view>
    </keep-alive>
  </transition>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import store from "./store"
import Overview from "./components/Overview"

export default {
  components: {
    "overview": Overview
  },

  data () {
    return {
      state: store.state,
      refresh: false
    }
  },

  created () {
    store.restoreCreds()
  },

  mounted () {
    // Populate the store with our objects.
    // The Item component is expected to refresh the store as needed.
    store.fetchAll()
  }
}
</script>
```

Not seeing errors in the JS console makes this tough.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @saurabh None. The <router-view> component isn't rendering the component within (nor showing in the Vue Chrome extension, thus doesn't exist). Updated the question to reflect current state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `Vue.util.extend` here?

```
export const app = new Vue(Vue.util.extend({
  router,
  App
}, App)).$mount("#flightdeck-app")
```

Does doing this instead work?

```
new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#flightdeck-app')
```

Answer (score 0):

`components` should be name-componentVariable pairs like:

```
components: {
  app: app
}
```

Quote from the [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#components): `A *hash(map)* of components to be made available to the Vue instance.`